# How to retrieve dynamically created html tag value in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, variables

So I am able to create a tag name on the fly and add it to my html

```
$('#'+modal_ID).attr('tag', roleName);
```

Will create the following html div:

```
<div class="modal simplemodal-data" id="modal-1" style="" tag="Actor">...
```

Now my question is, how do I retrieve that tag information to use elsewhere?

```
var saveTagVar = $('#'+modal_ID).getElementsByTagName; //Trying something like this
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
var tag = $('#'+modal_ID).attr('tag');
console.log(tag); //'Actor'
```

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the tag attr

```
var saveTagVar = $('#'+modal_ID).attr("tag");
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName` Search elements with the tag indicated, but in this case, tags are nodes like `div` `ul`, etc.

If you want the 'tag value, use `.attr('tag')` It will get the attribute value of the selected node.